# jdk -version shows the old one different than the recent installed

Tags: java, macos

I have upgraded my java to jdk 1.7 (1.7.0_71-b14 <- System Configuration shows). But, in terminal, 'java -version' shows 1.6.0_65. I wonder what I should do to fix this.
Some say JAVA_HOME must be /library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0...., but I don't have anything in that folder. Some other solutions from the internet do not fix my problem.
I am using Mac, OSX 10.9.5. Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: did you reboot? It's clearly a PATH issue.

Comment: You should run `/usr/libexec/java_home` to see which `JAVA_HOME` is going to be used by default.

Comment: @RC. On OS X, it's not `PATH`-dependent at all. `java` is always in `/usr/bin`, and it's a wrapper that uses the same method as `/usr/libexec/java_home` to find the appropriate location.

Comment: Thank both for quick reply. I tried the command again and it still shows /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home. I need 1.7 jdk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)
```

Then issue the `java -version` command and if that doesn't work, try rebooting your computer like @RC mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I tried and I got a message saying... Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7". I am sure I upgraded to 1.7. Wonder why it doesn't change.

Comment: Open up `System Preferences` and click on `Java` to open the `Java Control Panel`. Click on the `Java` tab and then on `View...`. All your `Java` versions are listed there. Can you tell me what you see in that window?

Comment: Try `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7.0_71)`, if also that doesn't work, then I don't know what will. 

Also, what does just the `/usr/libexec/java_home` command return?

Comment: Still the same...  Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7.0_71" ..  msg from /usr/libexec/java_home --> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: I think you somewhere have the Java version hardcoded and that overrides your changes. Hopefully someone else will take this over, it's very weird. Good luck!

Comment: I fixed it. I just downloaded new version 1.8 and installed. It is located in the right place and works fine. Maybe something has messed up with no reasons. Thank you so much for your time. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it's fixed. No problem. ;)